# Dealing with time formats

Tags: r, dplyr

I am just starting to really use R and have been working with a dataset that includes time values. I am uncertain if there are any general rules or helpful tips to work with time, especially AM/PM or 24 hour time formats.

This dataframe that I have been working on has a code basically like this:

```
cleanIntensities %>%
    group_by(Time) %>%
    summarise(avg = mean(TotalIntensity)) %>%
```

It is currently outputting the whole data frame in a table like this:

| Time | avg |
| --- | --- |
| 10:00:00 AM | 17.6437029 |
| 10:00:00 PM | 9.0630531 |
| 11:00:00 AM | 16.9212513 |
| 11:00:00 PM | 4.9966777 |
| 12:00:00 AM | 2.1295503 |
| 12:00:00 PM | 19.8470716 |
| 1:00:00 AM | 1.4190782 |
| 1:00:00 PM | 18.7752443 |
| 2:00:00 AM | 1.0439443 |
| 2:00:00 PM | 18.8686211 |
| 3:00:00 AM | 0.4437299 |
| 3:00:00 PM | 15.5846995 |
| 4:00:00 AM | 0.6330472 |
| 4:00:00 PM | 17.7166483 |
| 5:00:00 AM | 4.9506438 |
| 5:00:00 PM | 21.6556291 |
| 6:00:00 AM | 7.7712137 |
| 6:00:00 PM | 21.9216336 |
| 7:00:00 AM | 10.7336198 |
| 7:00:00 PM | 21.3852097 |
| 8:00:00 AM | 14.6680988 |
| 8:00:00 PM | 14.3399558 |
| 9:00:00 AM | 15.3877551 |
| 9:00:00 PM | 12.0729282 |

I was wondering if there was any way that helps to deal with date/time in R? Do y'all know of any helpful ways to format the data and to arrange it so that time specifically is easier to handle?

Comment: Hi! `{lubridate}` is a fantastic package to deal with time. Take a look at this cheat sheet: https://rawgit.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/main/lubridate.pdf

Comment: It's a little hard to tell from what you've provided, but it looks like your "Time" column is character data, which explains the strange sorting. `lubridate` and other packages can help convert this to R's datetime format, which will then sort as expected, can be compared using `> < >= <=`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have data like this.

```
head(dat1)
#          Time measure TotalIntensity
# 1 10:00:00 AM       1      25.869454
# 2 10:00:00 AM       2      29.014864
# 3 10:00:00 AM       3      15.055026
# 4 10:00:00 PM       1       5.674864
# 5 10:00:00 PM       2       6.480238
# 6 10:00:00 PM       3      12.996940
```

You can easily get the `mean`s using `aggregate` without caring much for ther format of the time variable.

```
aggregate(TotalIntensity ~ Time, dat1, mean)
#           Time TotalIntensity
# 1  10:00:00 AM      23.313114
# 2  10:00:00 PM       8.384014
# 3  11:00:00 AM      17.776820
# 4  11:00:00 PM       1.168399
# 5  12:00:00 AM       7.009737
# 6  12:00:00 PM      19.640631
# 7   1:00:00 AM       5.532544
# 8   1:00:00 PM      20.548702
# 9   2:00:00 AM       8.509576
# 10  2:00:00 PM      17.705006
# 11  3:00:00 AM      -1.922801
# 12  3:00:00 PM      17.293739
# 13  4:00:00 AM      -4.448062
# 14  4:00:00 PM      15.827717
# 15  5:00:00 AM       1.019233
# 16  5:00:00 PM      25.799249
# 17  6:00:00 AM       6.160121
# 18  6:00:00 PM      18.491693
# 19  7:00:00 AM       8.040709
# 20  7:00:00 PM      24.649039
# 21  8:00:00 AM      13.159717
# 22  8:00:00 PM      13.084731
# 23  9:00:00 AM      11.334896
# 24  9:00:00 PM      17.210107
```

The standard time format in R is `POSIX.ct` or `POSIX.lt`. To convert your times into proper time format you can use `strptime`. Times usually need a date, I `paste` current date for demonstration. In `format='%F %I:%M:%S %p'`, `%F` means standard date format such as `"2023-06-24"`, `%I:%M:%S` <decimal 1-12 hours>:<minutes>:, and `%p` the AM/PM indicator. Note, that spaces percent symbols and colons are important. See documentation `?strptime` for more options.

```
dat1$Time_POSIX <- strptime(paste(Sys.Date(), dat1$Time), format='%F %I:%M:%S %p')

head(dat1)
#          Time measure TotalIntensity          Time_POSIX
# 1 10:00:00 AM       1      25.869454 2023-06-24 10:00:00
# 2 10:00:00 AM       2      29.014864 2023-06-24 10:00:00
# 3 10:00:00 AM       3      15.055026 2023-06-24 10:00:00
# 4 10:00:00 PM       1       5.674864 2023-06-24 22:00:00
# 5 10:00:00 PM       2       6.480238 2023-06-24 22:00:00
# 6 10:00:00 PM       3      12.996940 2023-06-24 22:00:00
```